# How to use the tkinter module on macOsSierra

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm trying to learn how to use tkinter module in Python yet when I run it locally I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emailer", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import messagebox
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I've tried `pip install tkinter`and `sudo pip install tkinter` which throws the following error :

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

And finally when running `which python` in the terminal the output is `/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you are using Python from a python.org 64-bit/32-bit Python
>   installer for Mac OS X 10.6 and later, you should only use IDLE or
>   tkinter with an updated third-party Tcl/Tk 8.5 (not 8.6), like
>   [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) 8.5 installed.
>
> If you are using Mac OS X 10.6, do not use IDLE or Tkinter from the
>   Apple-supplied Python 2.6.1 in Mac OS X 10.6. If possible, install and
>   use a newer version of Python and of Tcl/Tk.
>
> If you are using Mac OS X 10.7 or later, the Apple-supplied Tcl/Tk 8.5
>   still has serious bugs that can cause application crashes. If you wish
>   to use IDLE or Tkinter, install and use a newer version of Python and
>   of Tcl/Tk.

Actually you can use `homebrew`:

```
brew install tcl-tk

brew link tcl-tk --force
```

Have a look at [tcltk](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).