# Tkinter on mac shows up as a black screen

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

So here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Greeting")
Label(root, text = "Hello World").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

but the only thing that shows up on the window after running it is a black screen

[image: you can see the code and the window in this image if it helps]

Comment: works fine for me. source: I'm on Mac

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you on an ARM (M1/M2) Mac? I've been having the same issue with tkinter on my M1 MacBook Pro and I'm wondering if it's 'Apple Silicon' related.

Comment: @JRiggles nah I currently use a 2015 macbook pro with the intel chip so I don't think the issue is to do with that

Comment: @Ryan Can I ask what text editor / IDE you used to test the program out? I used vs code

Comment: @Ash- I also used VS Code. And if it helps I'm on a 2019 MacBook Pro

Comment: @Ash - good to know! FWIW, I'm also using VS Code, but I doubt that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: I faced the exactly same issue and fixed by install `python-tk` and `python 3.10` following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554984/6228210.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue with Python 3.8 and Mac os Monterey; I've followed these steps to fix the issue:

1. Upgraded Mac Os to the latest version
2. Upgraded Python to 3.10/ 3.11

My issue was fixed.

Comment: this suggestion didn't worked for me

Comment: This worked for me. I upgraded to Python 3.10.5 and it worked.

Comment: Upgrading to Python 3.11 fixed the issue on my M2 Pro MacBook Pro.

Comment: Cool - solved my issue with the different versions of python and white screens! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

After much digging, I've found a solution (with some caveats) -
you'll need both `homebrew` and `pyenv` installed for this to work. The idea is to replace your old deprecated tkinter installation with an up-to-date one that actually works* (and leaves your Mac's *system* Python alone!)

> Note that this will wipe out any packages you’ve installed with `pip` - back those up first! There is a plugin available for pyenv called [pyenv pip-migrate](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-pip-migrate) that will make this easier.

***Run the following commands***

1. `brew uninstall tcl-tk`  uninstall the old tk if you have it
2. `pyenv uninstall 3.10.5`  ...or whatever your current global Python version is
3. `brew install tcl-tk` grab a fresh install of tk
4. `pyenv install 3.10.5`  grab a fresh install of Python 3.10.5 (or whichever)
5. `pyenv global 3.10.5` set your global Python version (matching the version you just installed above)

You need to install tk via `homebrew` *before* installing Python with `pyenv` because `pyenv` will automatically try to use whatever tk package it can find when it installs Python.

This will also work if you are using `pyenv` to upgrade from one version of Python to another.

***Final Thoughts***

- If you don't already have `homebrew` installed, [here are good instructions](https://setapp.com/how-to/install-homebrew-on-mac)
- If you don't have `pyenv`, just run `brew install pyenv`
- You’ll probably need to select your preferred Python interpreter in VSCode again

**This worked for me - YMMV*

Comment: The black screen is a problem because of the Mac system installation of Tcl-TK. IF you run "wish" on the Mac terminal, you'll see "DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.". Installing a new version of TK and making sure it's on the PATH BEFORE the system "wish" fixes the issue - Brew suggests : "echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc". The Python-specific part of this answer is also needed just because pyenv hardcodes paths.

Comment: @Renato This is great info - thanks for digging into this further!

Comment: thanks to your answer I actually got TK working in Common Lisp :) so thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when updating to Mac OS Sonoma, my apps using tkinter and customtkinter stopped working and only showed this blank window.
In my case it was solved by :

1. upgrading to Python 3.12.1 from https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. creating a new environment for my project

Answer (score -1):

Install/activate and import all globally installed packages in a  new virtual environment by running the command:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv --system-site-packages
source venv/bin/activate
```