# Tkinter stopped working in my python environment - how can I re-install it?

Tags: python, tkinter, module, package, environment

I am new to coding and made a stupid mistake - I installed a requirements-package from GitHub (pip install -r requirements.txt) without setting up a virtual python environment for it on my system (Mac, VScode).

Now my Tkinter module stopped working (it still opens GUI windows, but the windows are distorted, empty or without function).

I can not pip uninstall Tkinter, it always says "WARNING: Skipping tkinter as it is not installed.", I cannot update it either. I also tried to manually locate the Tkinter-module and deleting it, but that didn't remove it properly and I still could not re-install it. As far as I understood now, Tkinter is an integral part of the python package...

Is there a way to fix this without having to set up my whole environment anew?

I apologize for my stupidity.

Thank You guys!

Comment: Can you post the `requirements.txt` file? Does it mention anything to do with `tkinter`/`tk`/`tcl`?

Comment: It does not, unfortunately, but thanks for Your reply! The .txt says: numpy==1.19.5

opencv-python==4.5.5.64

transformers==4.16.2

diffusers==0.2.4

tqdm==4.64.0

openvino==2022.1.0

huggingface_hub==0.9.0

scipy==1.9.0

streamlit==1.12.0

watchdog==2.1.9

ftfy==6.1.1

Comment: You can try installing a fresh `tcl/tk` package with homebrew (assuming you have it). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056296/tkinter-on-mac-shows-up-as-a-black-screen/73186351#73186351) for details. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank You! I will try this as a last resort if there is no other way because this solution would basically mean that I'll have to set up the whole environment again.