# Macbook and tkinter window

Tags: tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Kgd.jpg)
I dropped my MacBook off to get a service done on it. After collecting the computer, my Tkinter window doesn't look the same, and I can't get it to look the same as before. Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186351/8512262) help at all? Also, FWIW: Saying your window doesn't look the same as "before" is totally meaningless since we have no way of knowing what it originally looked like. You'll need to include at least *some* code with your question if you expect any meaningful help. That said, I suspect the answer I linked will help get you back on track.

Answer (score 0):

Before the reparation, my Tkinter window was white, and I could print messages in the window. I could change the background colour and do all kinds of stuff. But after the service, the Tkinter window is just black with the buttons I created. I can't change the background colour from black, and my game doesn't have the same functions as before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).