# Tkinter Label not showing text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning how to use tkinter. When I try doing an hello world example, text does not appear. A small window pops up empty.

My basic code goes like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="Hello World!")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you on OSX, and does the window come up black?

Comment: If I may piggyback off of @BryanOakley - Assuming you *are* on Mac OS, I may have a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186351/8512262) for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am on OSX. The solution you provided worked.