# Pycharm Macos Ventura 13.2.1 Tkinter GUI Black Screen Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-button

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHrR1.png) [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIqVp.png) After I updated my macos to Macos Ventura 13.2.1, I started to get black screen in tkinter python GUI.When I write the code attached, I get the attached output where the screen is black and the button is blinking. This even happens when I change the screen background to blue via config method of tkinter. Moreover, when I put a button to tkinter GUI screen, I always get a blinking button when I hover my mouse to the button. I have tried related Stackoverflow posts as solutions but noone worked for my side. Do you have any suggestions ?

I have tried to reinstall and then install the pyenv and tcl-tk libraries from scratch. I have tried to update and upgrade the python, tkinter, tcl-tk versions on my macosx.

Comment: How did you try to update and upgrade python? I installed the version supplied by python.org on my Mac and haven't had a problem with it.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: [this worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186351/8512262), hopefully it helps you too