# Content of window is not showing in tkinter on mac

Tags: macos, tkinter, label, window, macos-ventura

I am using MacOS Ventura 13.2, Visual Studio Code and Python 3.9
Tkinter will not show widgets inside of the window (Although the window does appear, and can be resized from the script using `root.geometry('500x500')`.

I also attempted in the terminal and it was the same. It was also the same with PyCharm.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

testlabel = Label(root, text="hello", fg="White", font=("Helvetica", 14))
testlabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I also attempted `label.grid(column=0, row=0)`
But nothing worked.

Comment: Try `fg="black"`. Does the text show up?

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.10 with python 3.10.7 your code runs properly.Probably a MacOs issue.See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056296/tkinter-on-mac-shows-up-as-a-black-screen) helps.