# Tkinter not properly displaying on M1 Mac

Tags: python, tkinter, apple-m1

Context: I am using an M1 mac on Ventura 13.3.1, and I've set up a pyenv virtual env using python 3.10.6

When I run my application (code block attached below) I get this blank window with only the label being applied:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('visual')
root.geometry('400x400')

text = tk.Label(root, text="hello", height=40, width=100, bg='red', font=('Arial', 20))
text.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

[empty tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTaAd.png)

I've tried every solution under the sun (if the sun was stackoverflow), and nothing relieves my problems. The only progress I've made is getting it to go from a black window to this.

Comment: This works fine for me on an M2 mac. Just to clarify: you're not seeing the red color and you're also not seeing the text, correct? And the code in the question is exactly what you're running?

Comment: it's exactly as you see here, and the result is the screenshot attached above. So essentially nothing, I'm puzzled

Comment: Are you running it from the command line, or from within an IDE. I'm not sure if it matters, but if you aren't running from the command line I suggest you try that to see if it changes anything.

Comment: I know this isn't precisely the same problem, but I have an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186351/8512262) that shows how to update tkinter on a Mac. Maybe that will help?

Comment: I've ran it from both the command line and vscode, same issue either way. @JRiggles I've tried that solution as well, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Tkinter to run on my M2 Mac by using Python version 3.9.1 with the help of a package manager called, Miniforge3 .

Installing Miniforge3:

1. Download the shell script labeled OS X arm64 (Apple Silicon) (***): github.com/conda-forge/miniforge
2. In your terminal, enter "sh ", drag and drop the downloaded shell script file to the terminal, and follow the installation instruction.

Create, activate, and install Python 3.9.1 environment:

1. In your terminal, enter "conda activate base"
2. To create a new environment, enter "conda create --name <ENV_NAME>"
3. To activate the new environment, enter "conda activate <ENV_NAME>"
4. To install Python 3.9.1 (or any version that you know that will work) into the new environment, enter "conda install python=3.9.1".

If you are encountering "Conda Command Not Found" error message like I did, you would need to follow these steps:
https://saturncloud.io/blog/solving-the-conda-command-not-found-issue-after-installing-anaconda3/

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: Hope that helps!