# Tkinter not working properly on MacOS 14.0

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am newly learning python and in my course we just started learning about the Tkinter module through the following code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, RAISED

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator')
labels = [['1', '2', '3'],['4', '5', '6'],['7', '8', '9'],['*', '0', '#']]

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        label = Label(master=root, relief=RAISED, padx=10, text=labels[r][c])
        label.grid(row=r, column=c)

root.mainloop()
```

Where it should post a "psuedo" calculator type image when ran, but instead on my Mac it is just a blank box where the title is correct but absolutely nothing else is there (like in the screenshot provided). Does anyone know why this is happening and/or what needs to be done to fix it?

[This is what happens when the code is ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LrBS.png)

I have not attempted anything yet as I am unsure as to what to do. I do have home-brew installed through terminal, but other than that I am at a standstill.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, this runs fine under Linux. Suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056296/tkinter-on-mac-shows-up-as-a-black-screen, it looks like MacOS may be using an out-of-date Python/TclTk.

Comment: I just followed JRiggles answer, and I am still nowhere closer to obtaining what I need. I just updated to Python 13.2.0, and reinstalled tcl-tk, and set python 13.2.0 to the global, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Here is link https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: The version of tkinter that comes with OSX is broken. You'll need to install a different version of python. I recommend going to python.org.

Comment: Thank you everyone, but I have downloaded a different python than the one that comes with OSX (python 13.2.0) and it still has yet to change anything regarding my output. Is there anyway to wipe the python and tk slate clean such that I can just download the latest python, and tkinter?