# Tkinter Label and Entry Widgets Not Displaying on Window

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I've encountered an issue with my code, which works on other computers but not on my Mac running Python 3.9 on PyCharm. The `Label` and `Entry` widgets are not displaying on the window, though the `Button`, window title, and window size are working as expected.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("GUI Programme")
window.minsize(width=500, height=300)

label = Label(text="This is a label")
label.pack()

entry = Entry(width=10)
entry.pack()

button = Button(text="This is a button")
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Here is the result:
[image]

I'm not sure what the issue here is, and any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305735/tkinter-not-working-properly-on-macos-14-0

Comment: Worked for me using Python 3.12.0rc3. I can see all  three widgets.   Did you update PyCharm?

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: I have downloaded python 3.12, so now there is no issue with this anymore. Thanks @toyotaSupra

Comment: Glad you got it working.