# background colour not changing using tkinter on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, game-development

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqbGRZx4xUc, to code up a game. I'm using macOS, and python on VScode. This is what I have coded so far:

```
from tkinter import *




root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry('1440x720')
root.title("Minesweeper game")
root.resizable(False, False)


top_frame = Frame(root, bg='red', width=180, height=100)

top_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0)  

root.mainloop()
```

this is all I have coded so far, however, my background colour doesn't change and even the frame doesn't show up. any clue why this may happen? I literally copied the code from the tutorial

Comment: This should help: [tkinter on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056296/tkinter-on-mac-shows-up-as-a-black-screen) I read a lot about problems with the preinstalled python and tkinter on mac os, so you might just have to update your installation. Your code works fine

Comment: Does this help `from tkinter import ttk` instead of `from tkinter import *`?

Comment: Your frame has a height of 0. `top_frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)`