Problems with python tkinter on macOS 14.7.1
I tried to run a python script with the code line
from tkinter import Tk

on macOS Sonoma 14.7.1
with python3 version 3.9.1
Running the script produces the following error message:
macOS 14 (1407) or later required, have instead 14 (1406) ! 
zsh: abort python3 _test.py

but I have macOS 14.7.1 installed.
An installation or unistallation of tk has no influence on the error message.
In a web search I found similar behaviour under macOS 11 and 12, with subversions 6 and 7 as here, but no solution to the problem.

This answer may not be explicitly related to your issue, but I have outlined steps you can follow to get tkinter working on Mac OS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186351/8512262
